# Can I use relative XPath expressions in libxml2?

Tags: c, xpath, libxml2

I am wondering whether it is possible to use relative XPath expressions in libxml2.

This is from the javax.xml.xpath API and I would like to do the similar thing using libxml2:

```
Node widgetNode = (Node) xpath.evaluate(expression, document, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

> With a reference to the 
>   element, a relative XPath expression
>   can now written to select the
>    child element:

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String expression = "manufacturer";
Node manufacturerNode = (Node) xpath.evaluate(expression, **widgetNode**, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the node member of your xmlXPathContext object.

Answer (score 7):

Here is some code example:

```
xmlXPathContextPtr xpathCtx = xmlXPathNewContext(doc);

const xmlChar* xpathExpr = BAD_CAST "//column";
xmlXPathObjectPtr columnXPathObj = xmlXPathEvalExpression(xpathExpr, xpathCtx);


// Do whatever you want with your query here. Usually iterate over the result.
// Inside this iteration I do:

cur = columnNodes->nodeTab[i];

// Important part
xpathCtx->node = cur;

// After which you can do something like:
xmlXPathObjectPtr screenXPathObj = xmlXPathEvalExpression(BAD_CAST "screen", xpathCtx); 
xmlNodeSetPtr screenNodes = screenXPathObj->nodesetval;
for (int j = 0; j < screenNodes->nodeNr; j++) {
// You're now iterating over the <screen>s inside the curent <column>
}
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: it works perfectly, the important thing to notice is that relative queries "tr/td" that are invalid when xpathCtx->node is NULL, become valid when you set xpathCtx->node for a query root